# Trim only the first and last occurrence of a character in a string (PHP)

Tags: php, string, trim

This is something I could hack together, but I wondered if anybody had a clean solution to my problem. Something that I throw together wont necessarily be very concise or speedy!

I have a string like this `///hello/world///`. I need to strip only the first and last slash, none of the others, so that I get a string like this `//hello/world//`.

PHP's `trim` isn't quite right right: performing `trim($string, '/')` will return `hello/world`.

One thing to note is that the string won't necessarily have any slashes at the beginning or end. Here are a few examples of what I would like to happen to different strings:

```
///hello/world/// > //hello/world//
/hello/world/// > hello/world//
hello/world/ > hello/world
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why not to bring a real world example instead of such a dummy one? May be there can be a better solution, for your very case only? A real case.

Comment: @col This is almost real world. It's part of a routing class which gets passed the current URL path to route through to the appropriate controller. I just noticed that `http://example.com/path/to/file` resolves to the same controller as `http://example.com///path/to/file//`, so the example above is almost exactly what the strings I'm getting will look like :) I'm handling paths

Comment: But what's the reason in having such multiple slashes? Paths need only one. I've never seen path like this one: `///path/to/file//`. Where do you get them and why don't you want normalize, making it usual /path/to/file/?

Comment: Oh, I don't **want** the slashes. I'm thinking very edge-case, like if somebody mistypes the URL. Currently, the functionality I'm looking for is tied to a configuration so the behaviour can be changed on an application by application basis. Maybe I am thinking about it too much, but I got an answer to my question anyway so I'm happy. I'm sure one day I'll have another use for this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First thing on my mind:

```
if ($string[0] == '/') $string = substr($string,1);
if ($string[strlen($string)-1] == '/') $string = substr($string,0,strlen($string)-1);
```

Comment: I believe the substring method would probably run a lot quicker than the regular expression.

Comment: This is very roughly what I'd throw together myself.. I would like to avoid regex if it's going to be slower, are there any stats to back up the speed of simple string manipulation functions vs regex?

Comment: @Rowan: no, there are no such stats, as it's _very_ dependant on the actual manipulation going on, sometimes regexes do win. The only way to tell is to benchmark it for your expected strings, and even then I'd say using the one over the other based on performance is probably micro-optimalisation.

Comment: @Kevin only if there are thousands of such lines. And good programmer should avoid such numbers.

Comment: Awesome, thanks very much. I've been warned off micro-optimisation before :)

Comment: As a minor optimization to the code above, the last call to `strlen()` can be dropped, by changing the last `substr()` call to `substr($string, 0, -1)`

Answer (score 3):

This function acts as the official trim, except that it only trims once.

```
function trim_once($text, $c) {
    $c = preg_quote($c);
    return preg_replace("#^([$c])?(.*?)([$c])?$#", '$2', $text);
}
```

```
php > echo trim_once("||1|2|3|*", "*|");
|1|2|3|
php > echo trim_once("//|1|2|3/", "/");
/|1|2|3
```

Answer (score 1):

This one is by far the simplest. It matches on ^/ (start slash) and /$ (end slash) and if either are found it is replaced with an empty string. This will work with any character; just replace / in the following regular expression with the character of your choice. Note for the delimiter character I used # instead of / to make it easier to read. This will remove any single first or last / from a string:

```
$trimmed = preg_replace('#(^/|/$)#', '', $string);
```

Results:

```
///hello/world/// > //hello/world//
/hello/world/// > hello/world//
hello/world/ > hello/world
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you you are looking for:

```
preg_replace('/\/(\/*[^\/]*?\/*)\//', '\1', $text);
```

Comment: Argh, can't you just switch delimiters? `#/(/*[^/]*?/*)/#`. However, you forget to anchor it:`#^/(/*[^/]*?/*)$/#`, and for effectiveness sake you might as well use `preg_replace('#(^/|/$)#','',$text);`

Comment: The difference between `/\/(\/*[^\/]*?\/*)\//` and `#(^/|/$)#` is why people are quick to write off regex as unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

A different regex, using backreferences:

```
preg_replace('/^(\/?)(.*)\1$/','\2',$text);
```

This has the advantage that, should you want to use characters other than /, you could do so more legibly.  It also forces the / character to begin and end the string, and allows / to appear within the string.  Finally, it only removes the character from the beginning if there is a character at the end as well, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another implementation:

```
function otrim($str, $charlist)
{
 return preg_replace(sprintf('~^%s|%s$~', preg_quote($charlist, '~')), '', $str);
}
```

Comment: This gave me `Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: sprintf(): Too few arguments`

Answer (score 0):

It has been more than 6 years old ago, but I'm giving may answer anyway:

```
function trimOnce($value)
{   
    $offset = 0;
    $length = null;
    if(mb_substr($value,0,1) === '/') {
        $offset = 1;
    }
    if(mb_substr($value,-1) === '/') {
       $length = -1;
    }
    return mb_substr($value,$offset,$length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for trim once characters

```
function trimOnce( $string, $characters ) {
    if ( ! is_string( $string ) || ! is_string( $characters ) )
        return $string;

    $stringLength     = mb_strlen( $string );
    $charactersLength = mb_strlen( $characters );

    if ( $charactersLength > $stringLength )
        return $string;

    if ( mb_substr( $string, 0, $charactersLength ) == $characters ) {
        $string       = mb_substr( $string, $charactersLength, $stringLength );
        $stringLength = mb_strlen( $string );
    }

    if ( mb_substr( $string, - 1 * $charactersLength ) == $characters )
        $string = mb_substr( $string, 0, $stringLength - $charactersLength );

    return $string;
}

echo trimOnce( trimOnce( '<div><div>test</div></div>', '<div>' ), '</div>' );
```