# Javascript regular expression: remove first and last slash

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these strings in javascript:

```
/banking/bonifici/italia
/banking/bonifici/italia/
```

and I would like to remove the first and last slash if it's exists.

I tried `^\/(.+)\/?$` but it doesn't work.

Reading some post in stackoverflow I found that php has trim function and I could use his javascript translation (http://phpjs.org/functions/trim:566) but I would prefer a "simple" regular expression.

Comment: Related: [Trim only the first and last occurrence of a character in a string (PHP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3834319/trim-only-the-first-and-last-occurrence-of-a-character-in-a-string-php)

Answer (score 260, accepted):

```
return theString.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
```

"Replace all (`/.../g`) leading slash (`^\/`) or (`|`) trailing slash (`\/$`) with an empty string."

Comment: I modified this to remove any number of leading or trailing slashes, by using "+": replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '')

Comment: What if the string is `//www.google.com`? `//` will be missed.

Comment: @IsaacFerreira you can use this one `/^\s*\/*\s*|\s*\/*\s*$/gm` it takes care of some possible whitespace before and after the slashes and multiple slashes adding the *

Answer (score 41):

There's no real reason to use a regex here, string functions will work fine:

```
var string = "/banking/bonifici/italia/";
if (string.charAt(0) == "/") string = string.substr(1);
if (string.charAt(string.length - 1) == "/") string = string.substr(0, string.length - 1);
// string => "banking/bonifici/italia"
```

See this in action on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SNNEv/3/).

References:

- [`String.substr`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp)
- [`String.charAt`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)

Comment: i think sometimes avoiding regexp will help on readability, but in this case using 1 line of regexp and 1 line of comment will actually the the job in a much more elegant way.

Comment: This will not remove duplicate slashes at the beginning or end of the string ("//banking/bon/ita//") which a regex like replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '') will.

Comment: I don't think it even helps increase readability, it just becomes a test of the extent to which someone can comprehend regex or not. I think most people can tell what /^\/|\/$/g does after a few seconds, especially in the context of other non-regex code. So in this case, the regex is better IMO.

Answer (score 9):

In case if using RegExp is **not an option**, or you have to handle corner cases while working with URLs (such as double/triple slashes or empty lines without complex replacements), or utilizing additional processing, here's a less obvious, but more functional-style solution:

```js
const urls = [
  '//some/link///to/the/resource/',
  '/root',
  '/something/else',
];

const trimmedUrls = urls.map(url => url.split('/').filter(x => x).join('/'));

console.log(trimmedUrls);
```

In this snippet `filter()` function can implement more complex logic than just filtering empty strings (which is default behavior).

Word of warning - this is not as fast as other snippets here.

Answer (score 9):

One liner, no regex, handles multiple occurences

```
const trimSlashes = str => str.split('/').filter(v => v !== '').join('/');

console.log(trimSlashes('/some/path/foo/bar///')); // "some/path/foo/bar"
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case that someone needs a *premature optimization* here...

http://jsperf.com/remove-leading-and-trailing-slashes/5

```
var path = '///foo/is/not/equal/to/bar///'
var count = path.length - 1
var index = 0

while (path.charCodeAt(index) === 47 && ++index);
while (path.charCodeAt(count) === 47 && --count);

path = path.slice(index, count + 1)
```

Comment: @benraay do you need help understanding it?

Comment: @MilenGeorgiev no thanks i was just saying this version of the code is less readable than the one with RegEx they are sometimes hard to understand but `theString.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '')`is really simple and easy to understand for people  reading the code , but probably slower than this one !

Answer (score 2):

you can check with str.startsWith and str.endsWith
then substr if exist

```
  var str= "/aaa/bbb/";
  var str= str.startsWith('/') ? str.substr(1) : str;
  var str= str.endsWith('/') ? str.substr(0,str.length - 1) : str;
```

or you can write custom function

```
trimSlashes('/aaa/bbb/');

function trimSlashes(str){
  str= str.startsWith('/') ? str.substr(1) : str;
  str= str.endsWith('/') ? str.substr(0,str.length - 1) : str;
  return str;
}
```