# Javascript trim double slashes

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, trim

I would like to trim `//a/url///` to `a/url`. There are a few questions on Stackoverflow but they don't work, solves another problem or is too long and complex.

The code below is working and is based on [Javascript regular expression: remove first and last slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840600/javascript-regular-expression-remove-first-and-last-slash)

```
function trimSlashes(str) {
  str = str.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
  return str.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '');
};
```

However it's not very nice to duplicate code like that. How would a regex look like that takes care of double slashes as well?

### Testcase

```
let str1 = trimSlashes('/some/url/here/');
let str2 = trimSlashes('//some/other/url/here///');
```

### Expected result

```
some/url/here
some/other/url/here
```

### Wishlist

- Just a single regex
- Shorter or faster is better

Comment: Adding to the answer below in one line: `const trimSlashes = str => str.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '')` is what you're looking for:

Result with both test cases:

```
> '/some/url/here/'.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');
"some/url/here"

> '//some/other/url/here///'.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');
"some/other/url/here"
```

Explained:

```
^\/+  # one or more forward slashes at the beginning
|     # or
\/+$  # one or more forward slashes at the end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another variation without a regex but with a functional flair. I don't know about the performance but I had fun writing it and seems less cryptic.

```
const newString = '//some/other/url/here///'
.split('/')
.filter(s => s)
.join('/')
```

**Edit:**

Just ran some perf tests and this is slower than a regex but it might be insignificant if used sparingly.

https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-functional/1

Comment: Nice with alternatives! =) However, there was an answer like this in the link I added and it also says "Word of warning - this is not as fast as other snippets here" so my guess is that it can be slower. Probably not noticable in most cases, but anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With regexes you must be careful of unintended matches. for example do you want to trim the slash when the text is "// and this is a comment in some line of text//"?

If you don't want to trim things like that down you need to be a little more careful with the regex, how about this?

```
let regex = /^\/+([\w\/]+?)\/+$/;
let matches = regex.exec("//some/other/url/here///");
let url = matches[1];
```

https://regex101.com/r/K8CnxP/1